# How to delete all data from an index using delete_ by_query plugin with ES 2.X versions in rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have upgraded my `elasticsearch` to `2.0 version` in my `rails 4.2.7` app and am trying to delete all index data using [delete-by-query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.3/plugins-delete-by-query.html#plugins-delete-by-query) plugin. How can i achieve this? 
i was using delete_by_query method like this

```
Elasticsearch::Model.client
                    .delete_by_query(index: index_klass.index_name,
                                     body: {query: {match_all: {}}})
```

But this is deprecated in ES 2.X versions. so how can i use plugin to do this. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of deleting all the data in an index, I strongly suggest **deleting the entire index and re-creating it**.

Deleting the documents will mark them as deleted, but not actually physically deleting them from disk. When the automatic merging process of Elasticsearch happens then those will actually be deleted. But, the merging process will consider certain segment files for deletions only and most certainly you will still have disk space being used by an index which has no documents. More about segments' merging: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/merge-process.html and more about the deletion of these documents at merge time - https://www.elastic.co/blog/lucenes-handling-of-deleted-documents

So, you should much much better by simply deleting the index and recreating it.

Comment: Thanks @Andrei Stefan

Answer (score 1):

You have two solutions:

1. upgrade to ES 5.0 which has brought the [delete-by-query API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/5.0/docs-delete-by-query.html) back into the core.
2. stay on 2.x and install the [delete-by-query plugin](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/2.4/plugins-delete-by-query.html)

Thereafter, you code will work again.

Comment: i have already installed this plugin. but i don't know how to use it in rails application.?

Comment: The plugin is installed on the ES side, you don't need to do anything on the rails side for it to work.

Comment: i guess i have to use some kind of query or method to do that right?? as i mentioned in my post?? correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: `You are using unsupported method [delete_by_query] in some_path_here This method is not supported in the version you're using: 2.0.0, and will be removed in the next release.`

Comment: If all you want to do is delete all your documents, then I suggest going with @AndreiStefan's answer. Delete-by-query is worth using when you only have to remove a selected set of documents.